# Parse a File with C++

Tags: c++, string, file, parsing, ofstream

I have created code that will execute a file and then will execute code and store that code into a .csv filer shown below

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace.std;

int main(){
    int foo = 10;
    for(int i =1; x<=8 x++){

      std::stringstream ss;
      ss << "echo " << foo << " | ./triad >> scaling.csv"<<'\n';
      std::cout << ss.str().c_str() <<std::endl;
      system(ss.str().c_str());

      foo=foo*10
    }
return 0;
}
```

The triad program is one that I am given and cannot change. I run basically 10 iterations on it and print the output of that to a scaling.csv, to give me the following output

```
Length:        10    MFLOP/s:    2541.29
Length:       100    MFLOP/s:    2515.85
Length:      1000    MFLOP/s:    3616.75
```

and so on...

does anyone know how to parse that file so instead my scaling.csv will look something like this

```
Key,Value
10,2541.29
100,2515.85
1000,3616.75
```

Again what gets printed out by triad I cannot change.

Comment: Why not just write it out that way in the first place?

Comment: It looks like the output is dependent on whatever this "triad" program is.  If this is a program you can change, great! Change it to output what you want. However, I suspect it is not something you can change.  You're therefore left with parsing the file and re-writing the content, which seems to be your question and leads me to ask you this: **What have you tried?**

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. You dont' state what `triad` is, or what its input format is, or why you're using it at all. Your question cannot be answered in its current form.

Comment: triad is a program that is already given to me and I cannot change the output. Basically I am given the output that I printed to a .csv file and I need to find a way to parse that

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
int main()
{
     string s;
     int key; float val;
     ifstream out("out.txt");
     ofstream in("in.txt);

    in >> s;
    in >> key; // key == 10
    in >> s;
    in >> val; // val == 2541.29
}
```

Put this into a function and you have:

```
void extract(std::istream& in, int& key, float& val)
{
    // same as above
}

int main()
{
    int key; float val;
    while (in)
    {
        extract(in, key, val);
        out << key << ", " << val << std::endl;
    }
}
```

But we're performing the input *after* we check the stream. This can cause problems. Let's have the `extract` function return a reference to the stream:

```
std::ios& extract(std::istream& in, int& key, float& val)
{
    // same as above
}

int main()
{
    int key; float val;
    while (extract(in, key, val))
//         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    {
        out << key << ", " << val << std::endl;
    }
}
```